# Fast certficate of negativity for objective value of mixed-integer linear program

Tags: computational-complexity, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming

Let $c \in \mathbb R^n$, $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb R^m$, and $I \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Consider the Mixed integer linear program (MILP)

$$
\begin{split}
f^* = &\max \; c^Tx\\
&\text{subject to }Ax=b\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad x \ge 0\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad x_i \in \mathbb \{0, 1\},\;\forall i \in I. 
\end{split}
$$

Here $x \in \mathbb R^n$ is the variable.

## Question

Is there an "algorithmically tractable" way (e.g polynomial-time) of deciding whether $f^* < 0$ ?

## Notes

- I'm silently believing that computing $f^*$ is harder than deciding whether $f^*<0$. But i may be wrong...

Comment: Oops. On second thought $f^* \ge 0$ is equivalent to saying that there exists a point  $x \in \mathbb R^n$ satisfying the constraints: $Ax=b,\;x\ge 0,\;c^Tx \ge 0,\;x_i \in \{0,1\}\;\forall i \in I$. Thus my problem is really just an MILP feasibility problem.